# Adding functions to lit web components in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-component, lit

I have a web component i created in lit, which takes in a function as input prop. but the function is not being triggered from the react component.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import '@webcomponents/widgets'
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'webcomponents-widgets': WidgetProps
        }
    }
}
interface WidgetProps extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement> {
    var1: string,
    successCallback: Function,
}
const App = () =>{
   const onSuccessCallback = () =>{
       console.log("add some logic here");
   }
   return(<webcomponents-widgets var1="test" successCallBack={onSuccessCallback}></webcomponents-widgets>)
}
```

How can i trigger the function in react component? I have tried this is vue 3 and is working as expected.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not handle Web Components as well as other frameworks (but it is [planned to be improved in the future](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11347)).

What is happening here is that your `successCallBack` parameter gets converted to a string. You need to setup a ref on your web component and set `successCallBack` from a `useEffect`:

```
const App = () => {
   const widgetRef = useRef();
   const onSuccessCallback = () =>{
       console.log("add some logic here");
   }
   useEffect(() => {
      if (widgetRef.current) {
         widgetRef.current.successCallBack = onSuccessCallback;
      }
   }, []);
   return(<webcomponents-widgets var1="test" ref={widgetRef}></webcomponents-widgets>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360305/19498660), React does not handle function props for web components properly at this time.

While it's possible to use a ref to add the function property imperatively, I would suggest the more idiomatic way of doing things in web components is to not take a function as a prop but rather have the web component dispatch an event on "success" and the consumer to write an event handler.

So the implementation of `<webcomponents-widgets>`, instead of calling

```js
this.successCallBack();
```

would instead do

```js
const event = new Event('success', {bubbles: true, composed: true});
this.dispatch(event);
```

Then, in your React component you can add the event listener.

```js
const App = () => {
  const widgetRef = useRef();
  const onSuccessCallback = () => {
    console.log("add some logic here");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    widgetRef.current?.addEventListener('success', onSuccessCallback);
    return () => {
      widgetRef.current?.removeEventListener('success', onSuccessCallback);
    }
  }, []);
  return(<webcomponents-widgets var1="test" ref={widgetRef}></webcomponents-widgets>);
}
```

The [`@lit-labs/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lit-labs/react) package let's you wrap the web component, turning it into a React component so you can do this kind of event handling declaratively.